# Apriori algorithm in R - print out to 7 decimal places

Tags: r, decimal, apriori

I have run apriori to create rules in R.

Now I summarize, but my lift is only out to 4 decimal places.

I need to get it out to 7.

Common solutions I've looked up like options(digits=7) aren't working. I need the minimal lift value out to more digits.

```
   support           confidence           lift        
 Min.   :0.010012   Min.   :0.40000   Min.   : 0.5778  
 1st Qu.:0.013574   1st Qu.:0.60730   1st Qu.: 0.9981  
 Median :0.020761   Median :0.82951   Median : 1.0496  
 Mean   :0.037072   Mean   :0.76839   Mean   : 1.2747  
 3rd Qu.:0.039003   3rd Qu.:0.93107   3rd Qu.: 1.2893  
 Max.   :0.953278   Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :20.6075
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide sample data and the code you used to get to your result? There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. 
Avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as images. 
Consider how to make a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and see how you can change your question accordingly.

Comment: It really depends on your data structure, so please provide some example data. For me, doing `summary(X, digits=7)` where `X` is a dataframe works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved getting minimum lift to maximum digits.

```
> soverflow <- sort (rules, by="lift", decreasing=FALSE)
> inspect(head(soverflow))
```